# Sending params to controller by GET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a search in my system, to do this I created a Model with some `DateTime` attributes to make search by periods of date. The problem is when I do commit the controller is receiving null params and I don't know why this happens because looking at `Request["param"]` it has not `null`.

How could I fix this ?

**Model**

```
public class SearchPropostaPropriedadeModel
{
    public IPagedList<ViewPropostasPropriedadeModel> lista { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime dtIni { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime dtFim { get;set; }    
    //Status
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> status { get; set; }    
    public int statusSelected { get; set; }
    public SearchPropostaPropriedadeModel() { }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[PermissionFilter(RoleType.Administrador, RoleType.Gerente, RoleType.InvestidorMaster)]
public ViewResult viewAllPropPropriedadeIM(int? page, DateTime? dtIni, DateTime? dtFim, int? statusSelected)
{
    IList<PropInvestPropriedadeIM> _lista = new List<PropInvestPropriedadeIM>();
    IList<ViewPropostasPropriedadeModel> _listaModel = new List<ViewPropostasPropriedadeModel>();
    SearchPropostaPropriedadeModel model = new SearchPropostaPropriedadeModel();
    try
    {
        int pageSize = 20;
        int pagina = page ?? 1;
        //params (always null)
        DateTime dtm = DateTime.Now.Date;                
        DateTime start = dtIni ??  new DateTime(dtm.Year, dtm.Month, 1);
        DateTime end = dtFim ?? start.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        Debug.WriteLine("Start: " + start);
        Debug.WriteLine("End: " + end);
        //Request (not null)
        String di = Request["dtIni"]; // not null
        String df = Request["dtFim"]; // not null
        model.dtIni = di == null ? DateControl.getFirstDayOfMonth() : DateControl.convertStringToDate(di);
        model.dtFim = df == null ? DateControl.getLastDayOfMonth() : DateControl.convertStringToDate(df);
        model.status = getStatus();
        model.statusSelected = statusSelected ?? 1;  
        _lista = new PropInvestPropriedadeDAO().findAllByData(model.dtIni, model.dtFim, model.statusSelected);
        foreach (PropInvestPropriedadeIM p in _lista)
        {
            ViewPropostasPropriedadeModel vppm = new ViewPropostasPropriedadeModel();
            vppm.id = p.id;
            vppm.dtPedido = p.dtPedido;
            vppm.investidorNome = p.investidorMaster.nome;
            vppm.refAnuncio = "#" + String.Format("{0:000}", p.anuncio.id); 
            vppm.valorInvestimento = p.anuncio.valorInvestimento;
            vppm.idAnuncio = p.anuncio.id;
            vppm.statusDesc = getDescStatus(p.status);
            _listaModel.Add(vppm);
        }
        model.lista = _listaModel.ToPagedList(pagina, pageSize);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Erro viewAllPropPropriedadeIM PropostaInvestimentoController: " + e.Message);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**HTML**

```
@model SearchPropostaPropriedadeModel
@using PagedList.Mvc
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("viewAllPropPropriedadeIM", "PropostaInvestimento", FormMethod.Get, new { Class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
{              
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtIni, new { Class = "form-control date", placeholder = "Data inicial", style = "z-index:0 !important;" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtFim, new { Class = "form-control date", placeholder = "Data final", style = "z-index:0 !important;" })

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.statusSelected, Model.status, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Status", style = "z-index:0 !important;" })

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
}
....
```

Comment: What is the culture if your server? Is it one that expects dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format (e.g. `en-AU`)? And does it still happen when you enter (say) `1/1/1017`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed to ` <!-- /globalization pt-BR -->
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />` on Web.config

Comment: And can I assume its now working?

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually, the param `DateTime? dtIni` works very well, only `DateTime? dtFim` doesn't. I am looking for what is this problem, but I still cannot find it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It still doesn't works. The param `DateTime? dtFim` still sending null but when I get by `Request["dtFim"]` it is not null

Comment: What does `Request["dtFim"]` return?

Comment: I get the value and make convert to DateTime. Example: `String df = Request["dtFim"];  DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(df);` in this way it works, but getting from params it doesn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157105/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fernandopaiva).